# Python library path precedence

Tags: python, path, libraries

I have this problem:

I have a module installed in `/jhub/_prod/server_global_unifieddata_hadoop_airflow_daemon/lib/python2.7/site-packages` which is ignored by python that keeps loading the one installed at system level:

```
>>> sys.path 
['/jhub/_prod/server_global_unifieddata_hadoop_airflow_daemon/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
>>> import backports
>>> backports.__path__
['/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/backports']
```

How can I use the one installed in the custom path?

Comment: This sounds like  usecase for using virtualenv. But a question, have you imported anything before that copy from repl ? It could be that backports have already been imported from system path and later references use that from the cache ?

Comment: I deleted any other path from sys.path, but it keeps searching in the wrong path. Also... If I rename the folder into /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages to backports_test, the import still works! So what cache are you talking about?

Comment: I found sys.modules, let me expand the investigation perimeter. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to rasjani I found where the problem is: the module gets loaded and cached during the setup process.

```
[jmailer@mid1-t029nifi-1 bin]$ source  setEnv.sh 
[jmailer@mid1-t029nifi-1 bin]$ python 
Python 2.7.5 (default, Apr  2 2020, 13:16:51) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules.keys()
['google', 'copy_reg', 'sre_compile', '_sre', 'encodings', 'site', '__builtin__', 'sysconfig', '__main__', 'encodings.encodings', 'abc', 'posixpath', '_weakrefset', 'errno', 'encodings.codecs', 

'backports',  <--- already loaded from the system!

 'sre_constants', 're', '_abcoll', 'types', '_codecs', 'encodings.__builtin__', '_warnings', 'genericpath', 'stat', 'zipimport', '_sysconfigdata', 'warnings', 'UserDict', 'encodings.utf_8', 'sys', 'virtualenvwrapper', 'codecs', 'readline', 'os.path', 'signal', 'traceback', 'linecache', 'posix', 'encodings.aliases', 'exceptions', 'sre_parse', 'os', '_weakref']
>>> del sys.modules['backports']
>>> from backports.configparser import ConfigParser
```